# How to set up a jetty JNDI Datasource connection to IBM i DB/400 database from Lift

Tags: jetty, lift, db2-400

I’m working my way through the Lift Application Development Cookbook by Gilberto T. Garcia Jr and have run up against a problem I can’t seem to resolve. I’ve copied the source code Chap06-map-table and I’m trying to modify it to work with my IBM i (iSeries, AS/400, i5) database. I was able to make it work with the first type of connection using Squeryl Record. However, I can’t seem to figure how to get this to work using a JNDI Datasource.  I’ve spent a couple of days searching the internet for examples of setting this up and have not found a good example involving a DB/400 database connection. Below is the error I get when I attempt to start the container and the code I’ve modified in an effort to make it work.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Bob

This is the error:

```
> container:start
[info] jetty-8.0.4.v20111024
[warn] Config error at <New id="dsliftbook" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.R
esource"><Arg/><Arg>jdbc/dsliftbook</Arg><Arg>
[warn]       <New class="class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataS
ource"><Set name="Url">"jdbc:as400://www.server.com/play2test;naming=system;erro
rs=full"</Set><Set name="User">user</Set><Set name="Password">password</Set></New>
[warn]    </Arg></New>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class com.ibm.as400.acce
ss.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource
[warn] Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,[file:/C:/Users/user/Lif
t26Projects/scala_210/chap06-map-table/src/main/webapp/]}
[info] Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTING
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 15, 2013 12:21:59 AM
>
```

This is the modified jetty-env-xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty  
/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="dsliftbook" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
 <Arg></Arg>
 <Arg>jdbc/dsliftbook</Arg>
 <Arg>
  <New class="class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource">
     <Set name="Url">"jdbc:as400://www.server.com/play2test;naming=system;errors=full"
    </Set>
     <Set name="User">user</Set>
     <Set name="Password">password</Set>
   </New>
</Arg>
</New>
</Configure>
```

And this is the modified build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "2.5"
  Seq(
"net.liftweb"       %% "lift-webkit"        % liftVersion        % "compile",
"net.liftmodules"   %% "lift-jquery-module_2.5" % "2.3",
"org.eclipse.jetty"     % "jetty-webapp"       % "8.0.4.v20111024"  % "container",
"org.eclipse.jetty"     % "jetty-plus"         % "8.0.4.v20111024"  % "container",
"ch.qos.logback"    % "logback-classic"     % "1.0.6",
"org.specs2"        %% "specs2"             % "1.14"           % "test",
"net.liftweb"       %% "lift-squeryl-record" % liftVersion % "compile",
"net.sf.jt400"    % "jt400"       % "6.7",
  "org.liquibase"    %  "liquibase-maven-plugin" % "3.0.2"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your Resource the attribute `class="class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource"` is incorrect.  You don't need to preface the fully qualified class name with the word `class`.  It should read `class="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource"`.  Fix that and as long as a jar containing com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource is on the classpath (is it provided by jt400?) you should be ok.

Comment: I removed the extra "class" and changed <Set name="Url"> to <Set name="serverName">, <Set name="User"> to <Set name="user">, and <Set name="Password"> to <Set name="password">. Now I get prompt for user & password (even though I think I'm supplying them) but now get new error that it cannot establish the connection. So, I'm researching that. Your application may not run properly
java.sql.SQLException: The application requester cannot establish the connection
. ("jdbc:as400://server;..."com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:524) ~[jt
400-6.7.jar:JTOpen 6.7]